# centos minimal installation static ip address

Tags: centos

I install centos-7 Minimal. Here is the capture of my ifcfg-enp0s3 file..
I edited from the online document that says it works, but in my case not.
and I almost gonna cry :(
[image]

didnt forget restarting network servicethe response of ping google.com:
"unknown host google.com"

what is it wrong here ?

**EDITED**

[image]

(didnt forget restarting network service)

Comment: Please paste text, not images.

Comment: I cant its in virtual box, without gui

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some things to try:

- Remove the double quotes from the values.  I've never used, or seen these used.
- Make sure the vbox nic is in "Bridged Mode"... Devices > Network Settings > Attached To > Bridged Adapter.  (Unless you are trying to do something else with the networking, and understand what you are doing).
- can you ping 192.168.0.1?
- try simplifying your config.  The following should be all you need:

```
    DEVICE=enp0s3
    HWADDR=your_mac_addr
    TYPE=Ethernet
    UUID=your_UUID
    ONBOOT=yes
    NM_CONTROLLED=no
    BOOTPROTO=none
    IPADDR=192.168.0.35
    NETMASK=255.255.255.0
    GATEWAY=192.168.0.1
    DNS1=8.8.8.8
    IPV6INIT=no
    USERCTL=no
```

Comment: bro fist two is ok, but third; I edit the post, what is this ? no I cant ping gateway..

Comment: Nevermind about that one... I think it was pulled from CentOS 7.  See the other bullet points I added.

Comment: Can you ping 192.168.0.35?

Comment: yes I can ping 192.168.0.35 its ok and now 192.168.0.1 says "destination host unreachable" why ?

Comment: In the vbox network settings... is "Cable Connected" checked?

Comment: yes its checked

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38797/discussion-between-cory-and-y3n3rrr).

Answer (score 0):

Do you have internet access if you set your virtual NIC to NAT mode and use DHCP? My home gateways usually fail somehow with bridged networking especially on wi-fi.

NAT mode has usually been good enough for me, and you can get transport/application layer connectivity by configuring port forwarding on your VirtualBox NAT. The only times I did had to use bridged networking were on applications that required direct access to the interface or network layers, e.g. a VM running Vyatta with OSPF routing enabled or a separate VM to capture packets on promiscuous mode using Wireshark.

Answer (score 0):

@Y3N3RRR , I faced similar situation till yesterday night. But somehow I overcame this problem. I will list out the steps which worked for me. Hopefully, they will work for you too :)

1) I created 2 virtual machine instances with CentOS 7 minimal. One would act as master and the other one would act as agent node.

2) I wanted these instances to communicate with each other and simultaneously access the internet.

3) To achieve point 2, I had provided two network adapters for each virtual box instances.

```
Adapter 1- NAT (to access the internet)
Adapter 2- Internal Network (Nodes communicating securely with each other. Bridged network is similar, but I won't recommend it if there are more than 3 nodes)
```

4) Firstly, I had checked the IP address of an instance by using `ip addr`.

5) I chose to have 2 adapters. So, I didn't edit `enp0s3` network configuration file. I left it as it is.

6) I edited the `enp0s8` network config file with following details. `sudo vim /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp0s8` .

```
  a) BOOTPROTO=static
  b) ONBOOT=yes
  c) IPADDR=192.168.10.22 (I gave this static IP range)
  d) GATEWAY= 192.168.10.1
```

save and exit.

7) Edited the `sudo vim /etc/sysconfig/network` file with following details.

```
NETWORKING=yes
HOSTNAME=master
GATEWAY=192.168.10.1
```

save and exit.

8) Added nameserver detail in `sudo vim /etc/resolv.conf`

append one more DNS

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

save and exit

9) Inserted the detail about hostname and its static IP in `sudo /etc/hosts`

192.168.10.22 master

That is your static IP and hostname

This will issue the problem of `"unknown host google.com"` .

10) Next is about re-starting the network. `service network restart`

11) check the IP details using `ip addr` . You can see `enp0s3` with **dhcp IP** `10.0.2.15` and `enp0s8` with **static IP** `192.168.10.22`

12) `ping www.google.com`

13) If you have one more virtual box instance, ping it also. It will also work. Example: `ping 192.168.10.23`

It should work now.

This is how I addressed this issue. Hopefully it will work in your setting. If the technical explanation is not up to the mark, I am sorry :)